# Ajax get method returns empty model

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a cancel button on a form that is suppose to (re)AJAX the original page... The problem is that it sends back the page empty without any data. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
This is my code:

```
 $("#cancel-price-button").click(function() {
        $("#client-pricing-container").html("<h1 style='color:grey'>Loading...</h1>");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProjectPricing","Project",Model?.Project?.ProjectPricings)',
            success: function(data) {$("#client-pricing-container").html(data); },
            error: function(data) {
            $("#client-pricing-container").html("<h1 style='color:red'>Ajax Error!</h1>");
            console.log('An ajax error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
                   }
               });
               });
```

This is my controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetProjectPricing(string returnMessage,string returnClass,int?id=null)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                var pricingDetail = ProjectDataAccess.GetProjectDetails(null);
                pricingDetail.Project = new Project();
                pricingDetail.ReturnMessage = returnMessage;
                pricingDetail.ReturnClass = returnClass;
                return PartialView("Partial/ClientPricing", pricingDetail);
            }
            var pricingDetails = ProjectDataAccess.GetProjectDetails(id.Value);
            if (pricingDetails == null) return PartialView("Error");
            pricingDetails.ReturnMessage = returnMessage;
            pricingDetails.ReturnClass = returnClass;
            return PartialView("Partial/ClientPricing", pricingDetails);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this are usually due to discrepancies between the shape or naming of the parameters your API method is expecting and what is getting passed from your view.

In your case, your API expects:

`GetProjectPricing(string returnMessage, string returnClass, int? id=null)`

You're passing the following object:

`Model?.Project?.ProjectPricings`

So, assuming that you have already ensured that the object (or its parents) arent null, you need to make sure that the structure of ProjectPricings matches the expected shape and has the expected properties. If not (or if you aren't positive it does), try this:

`@Url.Action("GetProjectPricing","Project", new { returnMessage = "some text2", returnClass = "someClass", id = 9})`

*'id' can be left out, since you have a default value in your method signature*